# HTTPのレスポンスは何バイト以上のものから圧縮した方が効率的か？

Tags: http

表題の通りです。
HTTPサーバーでレスポンスを返す際にコンテンツを圧縮することができます。
ですが、圧縮処理自体がCPUと時間を使うため、軽いコンテンツであれば圧縮しなくても良いのではないかと考えています。

このような計測、実験を行ったデータはどこかのサイトにありますでしょうか？
また、どなかた知見をお持ちでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

レスポンスの内容はPHPなどで動的に作成されたものでしょうか。静的でしたらファイル編集後に一度だけでいい（圧縮した結果がサーバーによりキャッシュされる）ので処理量は増えないはずです。

個人的な意見ですが、レスポンスがテキストなら(httpファイルならなおさら)必ず法則性があるので、以下のような場合を除き動的でも圧縮したほうがいいと思います。

- サーバーにものすごく余裕が無い
- レスポンスの遅延を極力少なくしたい（サイズが極小なのが前提）